# Reduce verbosity/frequency of Amazon S3 AWS upload ProgressListener?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am doing a multi-part file upload to S3. I added a ProgressListener to print out progress and it works great. Too great. The file I am uploading is several GB large and the messages I am getting logged are way too granular. I am getting several thousand of these:

```
2021-11-04 06:56:07 INFO  GenericSftpLoader:190 - transfered bytes: 8192
```

Is there any way to reduce this from printing out every 8192 bytes and instead something more reasonable like 1048576 bytes?

My actual code is in Scala but I followed [this example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/track-mpu.html) closely from the AWS SDK documentation:

```
TransferManager tm = new TransferManager(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());        

    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(
            existingBucketName, keyName, new File(filePath));
    
    request.setGeneralProgressListener(new ProgressListener() {
        @Override
        public void progressChanged(ProgressEvent progressEvent) {
            System.out.println("Transferred bytes: " + 
                    progressEvent.getBytesTransferred());
        }
    });       

    Upload upload = tm.upload(request);
```

Comment: Log the transferred bytes and only println, when they are over a limit.

Comment: Do you have a clean way to log the bytes? Can't do it in the progressChanged() method because the function is called again every time 8192 bytes are moved, erasing whatever counter I have.

Comment: You could log it as a field in the ProgressListener class

Comment: @Indoordinosaur - your listener is a class; it can have a `var`.

Comment: I think this will help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to get a solution. Here's what I did:

TransferManager tm = new TransferManager(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());

```
PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(
        existingBucketName, keyName, new File(filePath));

request.setGeneralProgressListener(new ProgressListener() {
    private Long myBytes = 0
    @Override
    public void progressChanged(ProgressEvent progressEvent) {
        myBytes += progressEvent.getBytesTransferred();
        if (bytesTransferred > 1048576) {
            System.out.println("Transferred bytes: " + 
                    myBytes);
            myBytes = 0;
        }
    }
});       

Upload upload = tm.upload(request);
```