# How to show progress bar while uploading/downloading/copy files to amazon s3?

Tags: java, aws-sdk

I am using aws sdk v4 authentication for peformaing s3 operations like upload ,download etc. Now my problem i.e. I want to show progress bar for running operations and the internet giving me solutions using TransferManager but I am using s3 client so please suggest me how can I use progress bar ?

**Here is my sample code for upload file.**

```
       public static String putS3Object(S3Client s3Client,
                                     String bucketName,
                                     String objectKey,
                                     String objectPath) {

        try {
            Map<String, String> metadata = new HashMap<>();
            metadata.put("myVal", "test");

            PutObjectRequest putOb = PutObjectRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .key(objectKey).metadata(metadata)
                    .build();

            PutObjectResponse response = s3Client.putObject(putOb,
                    RequestBody.fromBytes(getObjectFile(objectPath)));

            return response.eTag();

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return "";
    }

    private static byte[] getObjectFile(String filePath) {

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        byte[] bytesArray = null;

        try {
            File file = new File(filePath);
            bytesArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            fileInputStream.read(bytesArray);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fileInputStream != null) {
                try {
                    fileInputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return bytesArray;
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908385/how-to-get-the-progress-status-of-the-file-uploaded-to-amazon-s3-using-java

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69835516/reduce-verbosity-frequency-of-amazon-s3-aws-upload-progresslistener